# Package Say does not exist

Tags: java, package

I was coding in java to test out packages. I have a folder called Demo inside Demo I have 2 folders, one called Say and the other folder Called OtherMainClass.

in Say folder I have a class called SayClass.java
here is code:

```
package Say;

public class SayClass {
public void sayTestMessage() {
    System.out.println("This is a test");
  }
}
```

in OtherMainClass folder I have a file called OtherMain.java here is code:

```
import Say.*;

public class OtherMain {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      SayClass s = new SayClass();

      s.sayTestMessage();
   }
}
```

when I compile OtherMain.java I get the following error:

```
OtherMain.java:1: error: package Say does not exist
import Say.*;
^
OtherMain.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    SayClass s = new SayClass();
    ^
symbol:   class SayClass
location: class OtherMain
OtherMain.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
      SayClass s = new SayClass();
                     ^
symbol:   class SayClass
location: class OtherMain
3 errors
```

Why can't java find the Say package? If I am understanding packages wrong then please explain what I am doing wrong and what is right.

Comment: *Where* you compile from matters; package names follow the directory names.

Comment: @failedProgrammer I'm not sure what you're trying to say--if they're having problems with this, Maven/Ant/Gradle certainly won't help. There's no need to jump to a build/dependency system to understand package naming or directory conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use below statement while importing in OtherMain

```
import Demo.Say.SayClass
```

Also package name convention is lowercase so kindly refactor your code to use from Say to say and Demo to demo .
And also while creating SayClass use package demo.say . So your code should be like

```
package demo.say;
public class SayClass {
public void sayTestMessage() {
    System.out.println("This is a test");
  }
}
```

after you are done renaming all the packages to lowercase then you can use

```
import demo.say.SayClass
```

or

```
import demo.say.*
```

in OtherMain class

Suggestions:
Its better to use standard community version of IDEs like Intellij Idea, Eclipse, etc  which automatically takes care of package naming, convention and lots of other house-care stuff

and go through the java naming convention docs/tutorials like https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions